# entity savedAndFlushed not found later in the same transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a loop where I persist in DB some new objects if they are not already existing. (`productPrice.product`)

But in my loop, it does not find a previously persisted entity (with save and flush), and the re-creation of the entity triggers an DataIntegrityViolationException because my unique constraint is violated (`ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_product_b2c_ext_id"`)

Here is my code (simplified). I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void myFunction(List<ProductPriceCatalogResponseAPI.ProductPrice> productPrices) {

    for (ProductPriceCatalogResponseAPI.ProductPrice productPrice : productPrices) {

        ProductPriceB2C pp = new ProductPriceB2C();
        pp.setProduct(productB2CRepository.findByExtId(productPrice.getProduct().getId())
                .orElse(createNewProductFromExtId(productPrice.getProduct())));

        productPriceB2CRepository.saveAndFlush(pp)
    }
}


private ProductB2C createNewProductFromExtId(ProductPriceCatalogResponseAPI.Product product) {
    ProductB2C p = new ProductB2C();
    p.setName(product.getLabel());
    p.setExtId(product.getId());
    log.info("Persist product {} with external id {}", product.getLabel(), product.getId());
    return productB2CRepository.saveAndFlush(p); // Exception here
}
```

ps : there is no cascade at all between `ProductPrice` and `Product`

Here is the code of my entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_b2c")
public class ProductB2C {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_b2c_generator", sequenceName = "product_b2c_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 10000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_b2c_generator")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "ext_id")
    private Long extId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // getters and setters
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "product_price_b2c")
public class ProductPriceB2C extends AbstractAuditingEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "product_price_b2c_generator", sequenceName = "product_price_b2c_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 10000)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "product_price_b2c_generator")
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private ProductB2C product;

    // other fields

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: In my sub function (createNewProduct...), when I call productB2CRepository.findByExtId(product.getId()); it finds something whereas this sub function is called only if productB2CRepository.findByExtId(product.getId()); returns empty..

Comment: Can you please include your entity classes in the question?

Comment: it's done. thx for your time. It's really strange because in the sub-function the entity is found but not in the main one.

Comment: Hmmm i think I know why it does not work, lamba functions had never behaved like standard code. It feels like they have a custom repo flushing boundaries. Tomorrow I'll try replace the "orElse" by  and "if (entity == null)"

Comment: I confirm. calling the function to saveAndFlush inside the orElse lamba causes the issue...